# How to explicitly expand a class function in terms of irreducible characters?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of exponent $n$ and let $d\mid n$. Consider the class function 
$$
f(g) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & g^d =1\\0&\textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
As a class function $f$ can be written as $f= \sum_{\chi} c_{\chi} \chi$, with 
$$
c_{\chi} =\left<f,\chi \right> = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g^d=1} \chi(g)
$$ 
and where $\chi$ runs over the irreducible characters of $G$.

> **Q.** Is there an explicit formula for $c_{\chi}$?

The question is motivated by the fact that when $G$ is cyclic there is a nice formula: Write $n=dk$, then $f = \sum_{\chi^k=1} \chi$.

Comment: Haven't you given an explicit formula for $c_\chi$?

Comment: When d=2 this is related to the Frobenius-Schur indicator.

Comment: @LSpice I don’t think so since I can’t evaluate it in general.

Comment: @Lior:  It does depend on what yiu mean by "explicit formula", but in any case I'm not optimistic about handling an arbitrary finite group.     Are there more complicated examples than cyclic groups?

Comment: @JimHumphreys Well, the formula I wrote above carries on to abelian groups. I do not know what happens, say, in nilpotent.

Comment: Isn't this just the Fourier transform?

Comment: @IgorRivin It is; but I hoped to as nice formula for the Fourier coefficients of that particular function of order dividing d as we have in the abelian case.

Comment: Your $f$ can be written in terms of Adams operations as $f=n^{-1}\psi^d(\chi_1)$, so you might find it helpful to consider the relationship between Adams operations and exterior powers.

Comment: @Lior:  Sorry for the long delay in responding to your comment.   I had in mind some highly non-abelian (say simple) group, which would be a good test case.    The point is that character tables are known explicitly for many small simple groups, permitting experimentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer.  Frobenius investigated such Fourier coefficients to prove that the number of solutions to $x^d=1$ is divides the order of the group.  He showed your class function is a virtual character, if I understood correctly, so all your Fourier coefficients are integers.  The paper of Frobenius is in German so I can't read it.  The paper http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~vishne/publications/S0219498811004690.pdf, and its references,
should give you some of what you want.